# Ganglia multicast with clustering

Tags: ganglia

Let's say I have two hosts. One acts as the server where `gmetad` and a local `gmond` resides. It also has the web interface. I then have a client that only has `gmond` configure as follows.

Anyways, everything works fine if i remove the `mcast_join` line from the `udp_recv_channel` If I leave it as is the UI doesn't show any hosts. I'm following the quick start guide found [here](http://jablonskis.org/2011/monitoring-multiple-clusters-using-ganglia/)

In my `gmond.conf` file i have the following.

```
udp_send_channel {
  mcast_join = host1
  port = 8661
  ttl = 1
}

udp_recv_channel {
  port = 8661
  retry_bind = true
  mcast_join = host1
  bind = host1
}
```

In my `gmetad.conf` file i have.

```
data_source "Infrastructure" host1:8661 host2:8661
```

Answer (score 0):

mcast_join should be a multicast address, not a machine's IP address (it seems, based on the documentation).  Is that what you're using there?  Is multicast actually functional in your network?